# static or non static functions in doctrine generated classes, symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

If you have noticed people write custom methods that deal with retrieving or inserting/updating records in db in two ways: 1. Static method 2. Non static methods(object method).

example:

get a records from a table A:

static public function getRecords(){
 $q = Doctrine_Query::create.....
}

public function getRecords(){
 $q = Doctrine_Query::create.....
}

is there are any point writing the custom methods in a "Object method" way ?
don't see any point in it.

Answer (score 3):

If the function is used to retrieve multiple objects for a controller, it should be in the table class and be a static method.

If the function is used to retrieve objects for another model object, and it's only used by model objects, it should be a non-static method on the model class itself.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but why then the "ModelTable" findBy* or any other methods are not static?